# How do I fix lighting glitches that appear on custom block models in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I made a custom model for diamond ore and applied it to a resource pack. However, when I applied said resource pack in-game and placed blocks around the diamond ore certain sides of the diamond ore model got shadowed out. I am pretty sure that this is because minecraft doesn't think that those sides of the model should be rendered, because technically that side of the model has a block on it, but if there is a way around this I would like to know.

How the ores look in game:
[image: How the ores look in-game]

How they are supposed to look (achieved by setting gamma to 1000 in options.txt):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you set the cullface value for all faces to the appropriate side, lighting issues should be fixed.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Model#Block_models

> cullface: Specifies whether a face does not need to be rendered when
> there is a block touching it in the specified position. The position
> can be: down, up, north, south, west, or east. It also determines the
> side of the block to use the light level from for lighting the face,
> and if unset, defaults to the side. bottom may also be used in the
> latest versions instead of down, despite appearing only once in the
> actual game assets.