# Custom model problems

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I am having two problems with custom models in my resource pack. I am not sure, but I think that they are related. I have looked everywhere and found [this](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/resource-packs/resource-pack-help/2468128-custom-model-glitch) and [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/371183/how-do-i-fix-lighting-glitches-that-appear-on-custom-block-models-in-minecraft).

> you cannot give a solid block a model like that

Is there any way of fixing it? Here is a screenshot with both problems:
[image: tree problem]

Comment: I can't seem to infer what problem you're trying to solve. Well, at least not with 100% accuracy. Are you asking for help with the fact that your block has a base color that is not grass, and therefore stands out? That's the only issue I see.

Comment: @Tacoタコス I want to solve the problem that the diagonal sides are dark and that when you look under it you see void and not grass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the post you linked specifies, due to how Minecraft renders textures, blocks which should be solid will remove textures connecting to other solid blocks. It's why the post has a screenshot showing why a slab works, but not solid dirt.

Your best bet would be to, maybe, create a texture for the bottom, or simply not use that model.

Comment: Is there any way of fixing it?

Comment: as i said, your best bets are only to make a texture of some form for the bottom or to not use that model

Comment: OK. But how do I make Minecraft think that it was never a full block in the first place?